# Unable to assign Subnet mask 255.255.255.255. The combination of IP and subnet mask is invalid

Tags: networking, ip, windows-server-2003, subnet

I am trying to set a subnet mask and IP address as below for Windows 2003 Server. Getting error as:

> The combination of IP and subnet mask is invalid. All of the bits in the host address portion of the IP Address are set to 1. Please enter the valid of IP Address and Subnet mask

```
IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 170.116.210.76

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: That is not a valid subnet mask. The error message tells you exactly the problem with it.

Comment: @n8te honestly that error message is awful. It assumes that the user knows how to convert a dotted-decimal subnet mask into binary, and that the user knows how to interpret such a message. A normal person would say "Uhh none of my bits are set to 1, they are set to 2, 5 and 5"

Comment: @MarkHenderson - You're right. I was going to edit that comment and add more info but then superuser went down for maintenance right as I started typing.

Comment: It should be pointed out that you shouldn't be using Windows Server 2003 in a production environment any more as it no longer receives security updates.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, 255.255.255.255 (/32) is not a valid subnet mask. There are situations where that *is* a valid subnet mask, which is when you have a peer to peer link on a platform that supports that subnet mask (think ADSL on a router. You can also configure ethernet links with a /32 in Linux with certain networking flags, but requires you to run a routing daemon to get any traffic anywhere).

The minimum subnet size for a normal or older device is /31 (255.255.255.254)